# Testing ZXing - some discoveries

Tags: c++, zxing

Just to start off, thanks for making ZXing freely available.

I have been working in the barcode field since '98, and have a fair bit of experience decoding barcodes from images.

I consult now, and one of my products in a program that tests barcode decoders. This is an extremely CPU intensive test, with literally millions of images being tested per symbology. I test with different amounts of blur, different angles, different brightness and contrast, different sizes (pixels per module), curvature, perspective distortion, ripple, varying illumination ... the whole shebang. I am testing the C++ implementation on a Linux machine.

I have come across a few issues that may interest the developers:

1) Aztec has a bug that crashes sometimes. In AztecDecoder.cpp, in Decoder::correctBits, sometimes numECCCodewords takes on a negative value. Bad things happen after that. I was able to patch with a simple test and a "throw" to complete my testing.

2) Aztec has a huge memory leak. In no time at all, my program is taking over one GB of RAM, and the number steadily increases over time. It gets bad enough that the OS starts bogging down and reboots after a while. I don't seem to have this problem with other symbologies.

3) You don't seem to make the version number available in the code. I know, you should keep track of which version you downloaded. Life isn't always like that, sometimes you inherit code, and you had nothing to do with downloading it. Even a simple #define in a header file would suffice. I like to display the version number of the decoder in my test program. I get this value directly from the decoder so that if I upgrade decoders, the reported version automatically changes. Just a nice thing to have.

4) Aztec appears to be extremely weak. I know, it's only alpha, but it hardly ever decodes. I am not meaning to pick on aztec, but it gave me the most issues.

5) The entire UPC family misdecodes (returns incorrect information for a correctly encoded barcode) extremely frequently. You may want to put some protection in there. ITF does a fair bit as well. All well-known weaknesses.

6) Aztec misdecodes as well. This should pretty well never happen with a Reed-Solomon error correction system. I haven't taken the time to look into this yet.

Those were the major problems, now for comments:

1) There is no support for barcodes at angles (omnidirectional decoding). This is supported by all major commercial packages.

2) Decoding appears to be weak overall in terms of handling blur, and low pixels per module. Yes, I realize that it is a free package, but just stating the weak points.

That's about all that I found now. I'll update when I have more information.

Comment: Why do you write that here, instead of to the ZXing group?

Comment: I signed up in the ZXing group, and there was no way to actually leave a message, oddly enough. Perhaps just something on my machine - I can view the messages, but not leave one.